# GatsbyJs - What's the best way to store Strings/Text for Static Websites

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, material-ui, gatsby

Am trying to create a Website with Gatsby JS and Material UI . What's the preferred way to store the site content . The site would be just a promotional website for a Small Business.

DO I just the keep the text in the components . Or do i need to keep it under a separate file(.md)/json and retrieve it using graphQl .

Any suggestions would be helpful .
Thanks

Comment: I voted to close this question because this really depends on what you personally want and there are countless options. It's totally fine to store the content inside components, or render them via `.md` or [`.mdx`](https://github.com/mdx-js/mdx) files. You can also think about adding CMS-like functionality and load in the content via [Contentful](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/using-contentful), [Wordpress](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/using-wordpress), or [something else](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples).

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the text in components is the preferred option considering it is much easier to implement.

Using a separate file is possible but it can get very complicated. Since you said it's only a simple website for a small business i would go for the first option. (I really don't have a lot of information to go on though)